# What could possibly go wrong on this?

Tags: c++, class

```
class root
{
    string name;
    public:
    root();
    root(string Name)
    {
        Name=name;
    }
    ~root();
    void setName(string Name)
    {
        name=Name;
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string name("name");
    root Root(name);
    Root.setName("name");
    cout<<Root.getName();
}
```

Then my program runs smoothly, but why won't my program run if I have

```
   root Root; //this had to be legal, right?
```

And, why should I have

```
root Root(name); //declaring?
```

and again

```
root setName(name);
```

Doesn't it had to work with:

```
root Root; //??
```

Comment: You don't have a body for the default constructor: `root(){}`

Comment: Consider declaring `root(string Name)` as `explicit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add to your `root()` constructor body `{}`
2. Fix your `root( string Name )` constructor. It should be:

.

```
root(string Name)
{
    name=Name; // <--- notice reversed order.
}
```

If I may suggest, you could use `const` and `&` reference instead:

```
root( const string& Name )
{
    name=Name;
}
```

Comment: Is it better if I use reference?

Comment: In theory, the compiler with proper optimization should see that you do not need to copy object of the `string` type, and would use a reference, but sometimes optimization may not work so well, so writing `const type& variable` is a way to ensure that you are willing to get a reference only, and you will not be changing it.

Comment: Or, better still, `root(const string &Name) : name(Name) {}`.

Comment: +1 to @JonathanLeffler. I should have written this way myself.

Answer (score 1):

In your class description you've declared `root()` but you do not provide a definition for the function.

So when you do `root Root` you're trying to call a default constructor which does not exist.

Comment: And maybe it is worth pointing out that the code should compile to object code, but should not link — the missing function is a linker error rather than a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

why wont my program run if I have

```
root Root; //this had to be legal, right?
```

You declared but never defined a constructor `Root()`.

Also,

```
root(string Name)
{
    Name=name;
}
```

Whoops.  You assigned to the function-local parameter, not the class member.

Comment: This is another reason to use a constructor initializer list.